# Approximation of integral of $\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}}{t}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I saw the following approximation in the book [Conformally Invariant Processes in the Plane](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-114-s) by Lawler (Chapter 2, page 54), and I am not sure how to obtain this result.

> Let $x > 0$ and $x \to 0$. Show that $$\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}}{t} \,{\rm d}t = -2 \log{x} + O(1)$$

---

I tried Taylor expanding the integrand but to no avail, and I have no insight as to why this result is true.

Comment: So the “=“ in the above equation should be replaced with “$\approx$”?

Comment: I don't find it on page 54 of the book. Which section? You may be talking about the proof of Proposition 2.30.

Comment: @banana this is the first equation in the proof of Proposition 2.34, I just changed up the notation a bit for simplification. Maybe you have an older version of the book that doesn't include Chapter 0 so the page numbers are different?

Comment: @tia: thanks, indeed. I think I am looking at an old version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Too long for a comment*

Making the substitution $s=\frac{1}{t}$
$$I(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}}{t} \,{\rm d}t=\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}s}}{s}ds=\int_{\frac{x^2}{2}}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt$$
Integrating by part
$$=\ln t\,e^{-t}\Big|_{\frac{x^2}{2}}^\infty+\int_{\frac{x^2}{2}}^\infty e^{-t}\ln t\,dt=-\ln\frac{x^2}{2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}+\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}\ln t\,dt-\int_{0}^\frac{x^2}{2} e^{-t}\ln t\,dt$$
The third term can be evaluated
$$\Big|\int_{0}^\frac{x^2}{2} e^{-t}\ln t\,dt\Big|<\Big|\int_{0}^\frac{x^2}{2} \ln t\,dt\Big|=\Big|\frac{x^2}{2}\ln\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}\Big|$$
Given that $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}\ln t\,dt=-\gamma$ and $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4)$
$$I(x)=-2\ln x+\ln2-\gamma+O(x^2\ln x)$$

Comment: @banana $\ln t\,e^{-t}\Big|_{\frac{x^2}{2}}^\infty=\ln t\,e^{-t}|_{t=\infty}-\ln t\,e^{-t}|_{t=\frac{x^2}{2}}$. Yes, there is a typo - just correcting. Thank you.

Comment: +1. You are welcome :-)